# Running a python script from the command line in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to run [SnakeFood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), to analyze a python project. I'm on a Windows machine and so far I've been able to figure out how to:

- install Tortoise for Mercurial to download the SnakeFood code from the site
- set the windows Path to accept python from the command prompt so I could do `python setup.py install` and got snakefood to go into my "site-packages" folder

Now, the documentation doesn't say anything else rather than:
`sfood /path/to/my/project`

I can't get this command to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work?

```
python "DriveLetter:\path\to\sfood.py" "DriveLetter:\path\to\your\project"
```

Comment: It does. The install doesn't install sfood in the site packages, only other functions that it needs. I had to go back to the downloaded files to find sfood in the bin folder. If I use the path of the `bin` in the downloaded folder then it seems like it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the documentation says "sfood /path/to/my/project" it most likely assumes a *nix environment. That leads me to the assumption that sfood probably has a shebang line.

On Windows you probably need to use "python sfood ". If "sfood" isn't in your PATH, you'll need to write the full path rather than just "sfood".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue, on my Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7.3 installed, like so:

```
C:\> cd \path\to\snakefood\installation\folder
C:\path\to\snakefood\installation\folder> python setup.py install
...
C:\path\to\snakefood\installation\folder> cd C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Python27\Scripts> python sfood \path\to\my\project
...
```